# backbone.js collection render html fullscreen api slide show

Tags: html, backbone.js, fullscreen

I am having trouble approaching this correctly.

I have a collection of slides that I want to click on to play them as a fullscreen slideshow.

I have a model:

```
var Slide = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
    title: "",
    header: "Slide Header",
    content: "Paragraph"
},
...
});
```

a collection:

```
var SlidesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
```

and a view:

```
var SlideshowView = Backbone.View.extend({});
```

I add the slides to the collection and render them through an underscore template elsewhere.

```
var slides = [{title  :"this is the first slide", 
               header :"this is the first header", 
               content:"this is finally the content"
              },
              {title  :"this is the second slide", 
               header :"this is the second header", 
               content:"this is second the content"
             }];

var sc = new SlidesCollection();
sc.add(slides);
```

I am not sure how to leverage the html fullscreen api to make a slideshow. Any suggestions.

Comment: You may want to read [Using fullscreen mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode) from Mozilla. Basically, you will want to enable fullscreen on an html element (i.e. a view) that controls/displays a slide show of `SlidesCollection`.

Comment: that is what I am having trouble with. I rendered a slide through a view and I added a click event on it to display the element fullscreen. It does work to the extent of displaying that element but how who I bind the fullscreen to a collection? It has not method fullscreen

Comment: You don't bind the collection to fullscreen. The fullscreen is only for a html element. You manipulate the collection within the view. The view is fullscreen.